# NavigationService.Navigate is all client side or is it post form to server?

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

To give a bit of background, I am asp.net/web form developer learning silverlight. In the web form world, if you need to navigate to another page from your application, you have options like Response.Redirect or Server.Transfer etc. Now when I do the same in Silverlight, I can create Silverlight Navigation Application and can do something like NavigationService.Navigate. My question is that when  i do NavigationService.Navigate, is it equivalent to submitting a web-form (POST) to server or is it all happening on the client side without anything been submitted to the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It typically happens all client-side.  Once the Silverlight XAP is downloaded, the only info that goes to/from the server is data, not UI.